# Planar Tracking

Tags: tracking

I'm not actually a tracker person, but I tried for a project and I can't get the result I want. When I do motion track, I can't see the floor and the wall correctly. I want to add a cube to the place I marked, I want to make an empty box there, I want to put a model in it, but I don't know what kind of track I should do. I can't find a suitable tutorial for this.[image]

Comment: Don't know whether [this](https://youtu.be/O3nohLIYKpI) YT tutorial helps?

Comment: I applied this tutorial but it didn't work. Object tracking gave better results but it didn't solve my problem. Why does no one track a building wall? There is no video on youtube. Everyone makes an easy track video so the tutorials are not helpful. Thank you for your help, I will wait for other answers.

Comment: Is [this one](https://youtu.be/Z8SwnRN701w) any better?

Comment: this is the first step if you follow a plane this is true but the plane should only be a maskable object so that 3d objects can be added

Comment: Ok. Someone else here who knows more about tracking than I do may be able to help.